# Asymmetric deterministic encryption (RSA) with Ruby

Tags: ruby, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to deterministically encrypt a value in Ruby using an asymmetric encryption algorithm.

For most use-cases one only cares that when you encrypt 'A' you get 'A' back when you decrypt it, that is you do not care about the encrypted value itself. You only care about the full roundtrip.

However, for an application that I'm developing I really need the output to be deterministic. That is, I need to encrypt something with RSA without a variable padding.

When I attempt to encrypt a value with `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::NO_PADDING` an error is returned:

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError Exception: data too small for key size
```

Anyone has an idea on how I can get a deterministic encrypted value using RSA?

Best regards,

DBA

Comment: Hi. What exaclty do you mean with "output to be deterministic" ? Do you want to have constant length of encrypted data? What are inputs?

Comment: When encrypting a value (e.g. 'xpto') you get back a different value every time due to the Padding. For example: crypt 'xpto' #=> 'aaa'. I need that when I run crypt 'xpto' again it also returns 'aaa' and not 'abc'

Comment: Got it. RSA tends to extend your message with random padding before the encryption. Does your code works, if you will disable "OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::NO_PADDING" ? Can you post the code?

Comment: The source file is available at: https://gist.github.com/745868

Comment: That padding is there for a security reason. You really should understand that before taking it out. The original data can be deterministically recovered even with random padding.

Comment: I know Greg. Thanks for the heads up, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from [crypto/rsa/rsa_none.c](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#XrPblB9f5NU/crypto/rsa/rsa_none.c&q=RSA_R_DATA_TOO_SMALL_FOR_KEY_SIZE%20package:%22git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/external/openssl.git%22&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc&l=76)

```
int RSA_padding_add_none(unsigned char *to, int tlen,
    const unsigned char *from, int flen)
    {
    if (flen > tlen)
            {
            RSAerr(RSA_F_RSA_PADDING_ADD_NONE,RSA_R_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE);
            return(0);
            }

    if (flen < tlen)
            {
            RSAerr(RSA_F_RSA_PADDING_ADD_NONE,RSA_R_DATA_TOO_SMALL_FOR_KEY_SIZE);
            return(0);
            }

    memcpy(to,from,(unsigned int)flen);
    return(1);
    }
```

Called from [rypto/rsa/rsa_eay.c](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#XrPblB9f5NU/crypto/rsa/rsa_eay.c&q=RSA_padding_add_none&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/external/openssl.git&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc&l=209)

```
static int RSA_eay_public_encrypt(int flen, const unsigned char *from,
         unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding)
...
               i=RSA_padding_add_none(buf,num,from,flen);
```

The `flen` is a message len; and the `tlen` is from: `num=BN_num_bytes(rsa->n);`

So, **You need your data have the same byte length as your `N` parameter of RSA key**

Also, as I know, your data must be smaller than N (if considered as single long-long-long binary number)

Comment: Do you see any way for me to get around this issue? A fixed padding would allow me to get around this issue, though I fail to see how can I do that using the Ruby OpenSSL lib.

Comment: Sorry for long editing and digging code, it is my first look inside `rsa.c`. Read the last line.

Comment: AHHH of course. Now I feel stupid!.. Thanks for the enlightenment =)

Comment: Thanks you for wonderful tour into the world of RSA C sources and digging in it ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could perform the padding to the appropriate key length yourself with non-random data